# Syntax error on SQL update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

How can I correct the following so that I don't receive a syntax error in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?

```
UPDATE Emp E
SET UserName = Left(FirstName,1)+LastName
WHERE EmpID=1
AND NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT * FROM Emp 
   WHERE UserName=Left(E.FirstName,1)+E.LastName
)
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with this, but dependent sub-queries tend to be *exceedingly* slow.

Comment: I've done this in the past but I seem to recall a code smell associated with the techniques described in the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To alias the name you must use FROM:

```
UPDATE Emp 
SET UserName = Left(FirstName,1)+LastName
FROM Emp E
WHERE NOT EXISTS(   
  SELECT * FROM Emp    
  WHERE UserName=Left(E.FirstName,1)+E.LastName)
```

Or alias the sub-query:

```
UPDATE Emp 
SET UserName = Left(FirstName,1)+LastName
WHERE NOT EXISTS(   
  SELECT * FROM Emp E    
  WHERE E.UserName=Left(Emp.FirstName,1)+Emp.LastName)
```

Comment: The first example worked!  Yeah!
UPDATE Emp 
SET UserName = Left(FirstName,1)+LastName
FROM Emp E
WHERE NOT EXISTS(   
  SELECT * FROM Emp    
  WHERE UserName=Left(E.FirstName,1)+E.LastName)

Comment: I would use the alias E in the first example, Update  E instead of Update Emp

This prevents you from only highlighting the first two lines and updating the entire table by accident.

Comment: @hlgem: Once bitten twice shy? :)

Answer (score 1):

Untested...

```
UPDATE E
SET UserName = Left(FirstName,1)+LastName
FROM Emp E
WHERE NOT EXISTS(   
                 SELECT * FROM Emp    
                 WHERE UserName=Left(E.FirstName,1)+E.LastName
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've tried this syntax... but in SQL Server you can specify a from on an update.

```
UPDATE Emp SET 
   UserName = Left(FirstName,1)+LastName
FROM Emp e1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM Emp e2
   WHERE e2.UserName=Left(e1.FirstName,1)+e1.LastName
)
```

**EDIT**: My syntax certainly runs but I'm not certain that it's correct.  Regardless of whether or not it's right, I would suggest using the alias in the update statement just to ensure that others can better understand what you are doing.

```
UPDATE e1 SET 
...
FROM Emp e1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 syntaxes here. To use an alias as the target of the update you do the following:

```
UPDATE e
    SET UserName = Left(FirstName,1)+LastName
    FROM Emp e
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT * FROM Emp
       WHERE UserName=Left(E.FirstName,1)+E.LastName
    )
    AND EmpID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, this is what you're trying to do. Though, I'm not sure the first part of the WHERE clause is really necessary unless there's a ton of rows...

```
UPDATE Emp
SET UserName = Left(FirstName,1)+LastName
WHERE UserName<>Left(FirstName,1)+LastName
AND EmpID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Emp 
SET  UserName = Left(FirstName,1)+LastName
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM Emp e
   WHERE e.UserName=Left(emp.FirstName,1)+emp.LastName
)